# is it possible to change text at the touch of a button in HTML

Tags: html

I have a problem where I need to change the displayed text between two different writing styles and wanted to ask if such a thing is even possible in HTML.
so like I my head I'm thinking about putting the text as a variable and saying
`if output = 1:`
 `display simple_text:`
`else display complex_text:`
Here, the complex and simple text would be the variables the text needed to change is set to.
Thanks in advance for answering and reading my question

Comment: From the question it is not completely clear, what you are trying to achieve. Could you be please more specific? Are you trying to change the style of the text? Some code might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`HTML` is a markup language intended to describe the *structure* of a document in a both machine- and human-readable way.

As such, `HTML` doesn't have any logic like `if...else` or *loops*.

So to do what you want you will either need a *template engine*  (which would decide at serve-time which text would be displayed, on the server), or *Javascript*, to implement the logic on the client-side (browser). Note that Javascript can be used on the server as well if the server runs **Node.js**.

To decide which one to go for, here's some cornerstones:

- If the decision which text to display must only be made once - and won't change after that, going for a template engine on the server-side is probably the best approach.
- If what is to displayed depends on some actions the user can perform (like you mentioned, clicking a button), go for a Javascript-based approach in the browser.